# Facebook> force a Device logout BEFORE access token is generated

Tags: facebook

I have a kiosk application which allows image uploads to fb.
After a successful upload the user is automatically logged out by passing the access token to Facebook.com/logout.php

But, after first logging in there are 2 permission dialogs the user must approve. If the user walks away or the application times out when the permission screens are viewable, the user remains logged in. I am unable to log the user out since the access token does not exist yet!
This is the actual facebook graph API call I use to logout

```
https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next='+SERVER_IP+'/logout&access_token='+ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Hope this makes sense...

Comment: You can not force a logout with a valid user access token. (For the obvious reason that if you could, countless websites would do a “drive-by logout” just to annoy people.)

Comment: Semantics aside, according to fb documentation, you need to pass a valid access token when logging out. See my revised question. My question is if there is another way of logging out a user using the standard Oauth flow.

Comment: Sorry, my previous comment was missing the critical “not” (wasn’t my intention to discuss semantics) - you can __not__ log a user out without an active access token – because if that was possible, nothing would stop me from implementing this logout on my website, in the background - and then people would wonder why they have been logged out of Facebook, without actively or willingly triggering this anywhere. So: Not possible. You _need_ an active user access token to log people out of Facebook via API.

Comment: Thanks. Seems I need to do a bit more research. My understanding of being 'logged in' is what happens after submitting a correct email+password. And if a user is 'logged in', common sense dictates that there must be some way of logging that user out via the API.

Comment: You need to differentiate between login to Facebook, and login to your app. The user of course needs to login to Facebook first (if they aren’t already), before your app’s login dialog asking for permissions even shows up. Now if the user did the first (login to Facebook), but cancels the second (login to your app) - then the user needs to actively log out of Facebook by himself. Your app can not do it, because it didn’t even get so far that the user connected to your app, so it has no “right” to log the user out of Facebook.

Comment: To clarify, the user is logging in to Facebook VIA the app. As mentioned in my post this is a kiosk app which uploads photos to a user's FB account. Straightforward. The moment a user gets past the initial email+PW facebook login, they ARE logged in to BOTH facebook AND the app or device. I can confirm this simply by going to https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=security&section=sessions for that user and checking for devices logged into. So I think my question is still valid but should clarify that I mean DEVICE logout as well

Comment: That all doesn’t change the basic fact: No user access token, no logout via API.